# Modify an element of a dictionary before removing it

Tags: c#

I need to delete a element of an dictionary collection, but before I delete it, I should change an attribute of its object.

```
class ColeccionAlquileres
{
    //creation of the collection        
    Dictionary<int, Alquiler> alquileres = new Dictionary<int, Alquiler>();

    //method implementation
    public int BajaAlquiler(int _identificador)
    {
        if (alquileres.Remove(_identificador))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Articulo dado de baja");
            //here, the code that allow change the atribute of my object.
        }
        else throw new AlquilerInexistenteException();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say _"change the atribute of my (/its) object"_, do you mean change a property of the `Alguiler` object that you are removing from the dictionary?  Consider something like `TryGetValue` before you do the remove.  If it succeeds you have the object in your hand.

Comment: Hey, it's 3 years later. You got 2 (very similar) answers to your question. We're either of them useful? Consider accepting or upvoting one (or both - upvoting only) of the answers you got

Answer (score 0):

You check the existence of the element and get it at the same time with `TryGetValue`:

```
if (alquileres.TryGetValue(_identificador, out var element))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Articulo dado de baja");
    element.Deleted = true; // (example) Set your property here.
    alquileres.Remove(_identificador);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like:

```
public int BajaAlquiler(int _identificador)
{
    if (alquileres.TryGetValue(_identificador, out var alquiler))
    {
        alquiler.Name = "Removed";
        alquileres.Remove(_identificador);
        Console.WriteLine("removed");
        return _identificador;
    }
    //otherwise
    Console.WriteLine("not found");
    throw new AlquilerInexistenteException();
}
```

Or, better still, use the "TryDoSomething" pattern for your call:

```
public bool TryRemoveAlquiler(int _identificador, out Alquiler objectRemoved)
{
    if (alquileres.TryGetValue(_identificador, out var alquiler))
    {
        alquiler.Name = "Removed";
        objectRemoved = alquiler;
        alquileres.Remove(_identificador);
        Console.WriteLine("removed");
        return true;
    }
    //otherwise
    Console.WriteLine("not found");
    objectRemoved = null;
    return false;
}
```

That way, you pass the removed object back up to the caller (and he can change the properties).  And, as a bonus, you remove the exception (for what is really a non-exceptional condition)